# Communicating between two C# exe

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, notifications, ipc

I have created a C# WPF project. I have two exe's running, both are created by me. One exe has a Window and another doesn't.

Now I want to communicate from the exe to the other .
I want to send a small message from exe (no window) to the other.

I really confused about this IPC in Windows C#, can anyone suggest me which one will be good for this problem

Comment: @sthotakura. Could you please share any links or samples .

Comment: @user2431170  Could you please use a search engine?

Comment: @user2431170 http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication

Comment: @JonathonReinhart. As I have already metioned, I was confused to implement IPC in C#. Sorry that I am not a Genius like you to find out everthing I need. And FYI, I have posted this question after googling for almost 1 hr

Comment: @sthotakura. Thank you so much. The tutorial which you shared is really useful.

Comment: @user2431170 He said "Use WCF named pipes". If you google that term, you'll find tons of examples, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353670/wcf-named-pipe-minimal-example).

Comment: Hi @JonathonReinhart. I have used the named pipe, but getting error in the endpoint. Could you help me ?
Server Code : http://pastebin.com/n16zCMbZ
CLient : http://pastebin.com/n0N2CChW

Comment: @user2431170 If you have a question with a specific piece of code like you've linked to, *that* is the kind of questions we want! Post that as a new question, showing what you've tried, what you expected, and the error messages that you're getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be rude in your comments.

Now try this:

On the client: create a client side proxy with the following few lines

```
// Create  the proxy:
EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/SomeAddress/PipeEndpoint/");
IMyinterface instance = ChannelFactory<IMyinterface>.CreateChannel(new NetNamedPipeBinding(), ep);

// now use it:
instance.SendMessage();
```

On the server side, run the server and register the object to do the work:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(new MyClass(), new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/SomeAddress"));
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyinterface), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "PipeEndpoint");
host.Open();
```

The MyClass code on the server side too:

```
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class MyClass : IMyinterface
{

    public void SendMessage()
    {
        // do something here
    }

}
```

And the interface should be in separate project referensed by both, client and server projects:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IMyinterface
{
     [OperationContract]
    void SendMessage();
}
```

Remark: when I say "Client", I mean the one who sends the message. Server is the one who receives the message. I think in your architecture is the opposite, so I wanted to be clear with my terminology.

I hope it helps

Comment: Hi Rami, I have used the same example , which was given by @sthotakura. I guess this also looks the same. But I am getting EndPointNotFoundException.

Comment: This is the message I am getting , There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/CommService/ that could accept the message.

Comment: (1) recheck the correctness of the addresses. (2) It may be a timing problem, maybe your client try to access the server before the server opened the pipe channel?

Comment: Please check the server code here http://pastebin.com/n16zCMbZ

Comment: And Client code http://pastebin.com/n0N2CChW

Comment: This code would not compile...

Comment: Rami, It is not placed in the same way like you see in paste bin. I just copied all the code and pasted for your reference. I am able to compile and run both exe. When I tried to send message from one exe to other at that time I am getting error as no endpoint listening

Comment: Hi Rami , Your code is working fine . I can get the response. But it takes more than 1 min to get the response :(

Comment: It should be match quicker. maybe the code in the function that you call runs long time?

Comment: Yes. It calls the interface implementation and it takes long time to come back

Comment: Does your function that you call from other executable does its job quickly if you called it directly in the same process, without pipes?