# No endpoint listening at net.pipe

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, named-pipes

I am getting the following error:

> There was no endpoint listening at
>   net.pipe://localhost/ServiceModelSamples/service that could accept the
>   message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.
>   See InnerException, if present, for more details.

I am calling WCF self hosted service inside windows service from another WCF call as follows.

```
                   _host = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService),
            new Uri[] { new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/PINSenderService") });

        _host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalculator),
                new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
                "");

        _host.Open();

        ChannelFactory<ICalculator> factory = new ChannelFactory<ICalculator>(
            new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None),
            new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/PINSenderService"));
        ICalculator proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
        proxy.SendPin(pin);
        ((IClientChannel)proxy).Close();
        factory.Close();
```

**Self-Hosted WCF Service**

```
 namespace PINSender
 {

    // Define a service contract.    

    public interface ICalculator
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void SendPin(string pin);
    }

    // Implement the ICalculator service contract in a service class.
    public class CalculatorService : ICalculator
    {
        // Implement the ICalculator methods.
        public void  SendPin(string pin)
        {
        }
    }

    public class CalculatorWindowsService : ServiceBase
    {
        public ServiceHost serviceHost = null;
        public CalculatorWindowsService()
        {
            // Name the Windows Service
            ServiceName = "PINSenderService";
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(new CalculatorWindowsService());
        }

        // Start the Windows service.
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            if (serviceHost != null)
            {
                serviceHost.Close();
            }

            // Create a ServiceHost for the CalculatorService type and 
            // provide the base address.
            serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService));

            // Open the ServiceHostBase to create listeners and start 
            // listening for messages.
            serviceHost.Open();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            if (serviceHost != null)
            {
                serviceHost.Close();
                serviceHost = null;
            }
        }
    }

    // Provide the ProjectInstaller class which allows 
    // the service to be installed by the Installutil.exe tool
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class ProjectInstaller : Installer
    {
        private ServiceProcessInstaller process;
        private ServiceInstaller service;

        public ProjectInstaller()
        {
            process = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
            process.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
            service = new ServiceInstaller();
            service.ServiceName = "PINSenderService";
            Installers.Add(process);
            Installers.Add(service);
        }
     }

}
```

**App.Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="PINSender.CalculatorService"
           behaviorConfiguration="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>            
        <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/PINSenderService"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>

    <endpoint address=""
              binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
              contract="PINSender.ICalculator" />        
    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexNamedPipeBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />                
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False"  />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
 </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- Make sure `IIS` is configured to use `Windows Process Activation Service(WAS)`:

  2. From the Start menu, choose Control Panel.
  3. Select Programs, then Programs and Features, or in Classic view,
     select `Programs and Features`.
  4. Click `Turn Windows Features on or off`.
  5. Under Features Summary, click Add Features.
  6. Expand the `Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0(or 3.5)` node and check the
     `Windows Communication Foundation Non-HTTP Activation feature`.
- Make sure **Net.Pipe Listener Adapter** service is running:

  8. Got to `run` & open `Services.msc`
  9. Make sure `Net.Pipe Listener Adapter` service is running.

In your App.config, you have used `baseAddress` with `http`, try changing that to `net.pipe`:

```
  <baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/ServiceModelSamples/service"/>
  </baseAddresses>
```

see [NetNamedPipeBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752247%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details.

**Update**:

You need to add `bindingConfiguration` in `endpoint` like :

```
<endpoint address=""
              binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
              contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ICalculator" 
              bindingConfiguration="Binding1" />
```

and add actual `bindingConfiguration` like:

```
    <bindings>
  <!-- 
        Following is the expanded configuration section for a NetNamedPipeBinding.
        Each property is configured with the default value.
     -->
  <netNamedPipeBinding>
    <binding name="Binding1" 
             closeTimeout="00:01:00"
             openTimeout="00:01:00" 
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
             sendTimeout="00:01:00"
             transactionFlow="false" 
             transferMode="Buffered" 
             transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
             hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
             maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
             maxBufferSize="65536" 
             maxConnections="10" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netNamedPipeBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: @ Pranv Thanks i have double checked both options are working ok on my machine. there could be some other issue.

Comment: @Pranv, If i update the App.Config to use your suggested code it gives me error when i start the service. "Service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some service stop automatically if they are not used by other services or programs"

Comment: Here is error trace from Event Log "Service cannot be started. System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [net.pipe].
"

Comment: ohh, that's because endpoint still using `wsHttpBinding` rather than `netNamedPipeBinding`

Comment: @Pranv, Modified but still getting same error. plz see my original Post for modified App.Config

Comment: Thanks @Pranv, service is starting now but another issue. When i try to call this service using named Pipe Code as shown in original post it gives me error : "Cannot listen on pipe name 'net.pipe://localhost/ServiceModelSamples/service/' because another pipe endpoint is already listening on that name."

Comment: Error suggests, another instance of same service is running, try with new the service name for test.

Comment: which service name you are talking about ? could you please elaborate more ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52185/discussion-between-pranav-singh-and-hammad-bukhari)

Comment: Now i am getting the following error "Cannot listen on pipe name 'net.pipe://localhost/ServiceModelSamples/service/' because another pipe endpoint is already listening on that name."

Please see my modified post for reference.

Comment: Thanks @PranavSingh :) You saved my day! :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error pop up. I was running from Visual Studio 2013, on windows 8.1. The solution for me was to run Visual Studio as an Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I also run Visual Studio 2013 on windows Server 2012 which is basically the same as 8.1, restarting it as admin also fixed the problem for me.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because I was using an [older tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20141027055124/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication), and trying to configure programatically.

The part I was missing was to supply the metadata endpoint ([thank you, this post!](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/168d7de1-d0f8-4f67-b989-d0746e76bec0/how-to-create-named-pipe-wcf-exe-using-netpipe?forum=wcf)).

```
ServiceMetadataBehavior serviceMetadataBehavior = 
    host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();

if (serviceMetadataBehavior == null)
{
    serviceMetadataBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceMetadataBehavior);
}

host.AddServiceEndpoint(
    typeof(IMetadataExchange), 
    MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexNamedPipeBinding(), 
    "net.pipe://localhost/PipeReverse/mex"
);
```