# PipeException on local WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm currently migrating a winforms app to WPF and the last thing I need to do is to migrate a WCF service

Config file sender side :

```xml
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="NetPipeBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" httpHelpPageEnabled="True" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="MyLibrary.WcfServiceController.GuiController" behaviorConfiguration="NetPipeBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" contract="MyLibrary.WcfServiceController.IGuiController" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexNamedPipeBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/GUI-ORG/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

Client side :

```xml
<bindings>
  <netNamedPipeBinding>
    <binding name="NetNamedPipeBinding_IGuiController"/>
  </netNamedPipeBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/GUI-ORG/" binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="NetNamedPipeBinding_IGuiController"
            contract="GuiUpdaterReference.IGuiController" name="NetNamedPipeBinding_IGuiController">
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

I have a wrapper looking like this :

```cs
public class GuiControllerClientWrapper
{
    private readonly LaunchType _launchType;
    private readonly GuiUpdaterReference.IGuiController _gc;

    public GuiControllerClientWrapper(LaunchType launchType)
    {
        _errorSent = false;
        _launchType = launchType;
        _gc = new GuiControllerClient();
        if (launchType == LaunchType.Manual)
        {
            ((GuiControllerClient)_gc).Open();
        }
    }

    /* other functions */
}
```

The exception occurs when calling Open() : `EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at "net.pipe://localhost/GUI-ORG" that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.`

InnerException is the following : `The pipe endpoint 'net.pipe://localhost/GUI-ORG' could not be found on your local machine`

and then a stacktrace pointing to my wrapper calling the open function

The thing is, if I add my old winforms GUI in the project and resintall everything, it does actually work, messages are sent and everything is normal

I have tried

- using diagnostics, but it didn't give me any information I can work with
- changing the address
- recreating/updating the service reference

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if "Net.Pipe Listener Adapter" service is running in Services management console.

```
Start Windows service -> Net.Pipe Listener Adapter service
```

[No endpoint listening at net.pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23510184/no-endpoint-listening-at-net-pipe)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I found the problem. Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, and it wasn't WCF that at fault even if the exception could have helped me

I have a service windows that runs everyday some code to check a local AD and do stuff
I also have a GUI that allows me to control the service and start the processing manually

When the button is clicked, an endpoint is started on the client (to have updates through a progressbar) but I didn't know that WPF rises an exception when a backgroundworker accesses the main thread (which wasn't the case in WinForms).

My background worker would start, read the data source and then crash, going directly to the `RunWorkerCompleted` event that closes the endpoint

Here's where WCF could have helped me a bit more : when I started messing around with the background workers, the exception changed it was now telling me that the communication channel was closed prematurely

My code now uses a safe access to the UI thread, which make the channel stay alive as long as necessary