# What is the best way to send data between different programs with different programming languages on the same computer?

Tags: c#, c, fpga, tcp, labview

I'm looking into developing a solution that can interface with a variety of languages (Python, C, C#, LabVIEW), where I can send data to and from the solution.
It interfaces with a FlexRIO system, where large amounts of data will be processed as quickly as possible with FPGAs.
The solution itself may be written in C or LabVIEW (my limits are the options I have software wise to interface with the FlexRIO drivers).

This software will accept commands that will be predefined (for example RESET:ALL), but the size of the data may be extremely large (like an array of 10 million characters).

So for example, I can write code in Python to send commands to this software and also get information back.

What are some options I have when it comes to how to send this data?
I was thinking TCP/IP, but I don't know of the speed and memory limits I may have.
Both softwares will be on the same computer as well.

Comment: You can use message queues. Look into RabbitMQ.

Comment: Why not use the file system?

Answer (score 3):

I worked on a similar problem. One of the solutions you could use is:

- Serialise data (protobuf, json, bson, xml)
- Compress data (gzip, snappy, lz4). The trade of is in speed of algorithm to size of the output
- Send blob to other app using Inter-Process Communication

The other side does the same in reverse.

I used [protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/), [lz4](https://lz4net.codeplex.com/) and [WCF pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353670/wcf-named-pipe-minimal-example), which worked well for frequent small-ish messages, but test it with your data.

In your case writing to a file and reading from a file may be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Pipes are one way, they are supported on all the languages you mentioned. It's a piece of shared memory, but the APIs mean it works just like a file or stream depending on the language.

One program writes into it and another reads from it, so like a TCP/IP connection, but with less overhead.

If you're clever about it, most of your code won't know what type of stream it's using. Then if you ever need to change the mechanism, little of your code will be affected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the data exchanges formats to take in to applications

1. XML
2. JSON

so you can communicate with out any hinderance

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at some transfer data between application methods throughout these links:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14740/Fast-IPC-Communication-Using-Shared-Memory-and-Int

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648774%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v23r1/topic/com.ibm.mbs.doc/designer/t_ctr_user_data_transfer.html