# Windows services c# to send its data to c# wpf Application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, service

I have a question regarding a Windows C# services.
Is it possible for the window service to run in background and send/Receive its data to a C# standalone application with opened by a user. if so how is it that it can be done?
Is there any other better ways for building a window service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can be done, and there are several options.  For inter-process communication - which is basically what you are asking for - you could consider WCF with NamedPipes or TCP, or a message queue (MSMQ, RabbitMQ etc).

Typically with a message queue the messages will queue if the service or client is not there, or with named pipes or TCP a current connection must be available.

[WCF named pipe minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353670/wcf-named-pipe-minimal-example)

Comment: RabbitMQ is free and a great tool. Been using it in production for routing messages for about 4 years with not a single issue. But if you just need to send to just a single client it's probably a bit overkill, as it really shines when routing messages to multiple clients.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You can run a service like windows service, expose methods, and one or more client can use it.

One example is [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/naresh.avari/develop-and-install-a-windows-service-in-C-Sharp/).

Bye bye.