# C# - Send data from console application to another console application

Tags: c#, .net

I have an XML file read from A console application and need to send value to B console application depending on logic in the following photo:
[image]

That's what exactly needs:
[image]
Please I need your support it's so important, Thanks.

Comment: Support on what exactly? What have you tried, and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Send like as in email?

Comment: @CasparKleijne I guess more like some sort of IPC (since the question mentions communication from one Console App to another Console App), but file based communication may be another possibility too... I think a bit more specific information from the OP would indeed be helpful

Comment: @bassfader i had edit the question please check it again

Comment: @CasparKleijne i had edit the question please check it again

Comment: Nobody is going to analyse those requirements and provide a solution.  This site is for answering specific questions you may have.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a WCF Service (utilizing NetNamedPipeBinding for example, if running on the same machine, NetTcpBinding if going across the network) to distribute the data to different clients.
You would need to implement a Contract with a "Subscribe" method for example where every client sends its ID so you can have a CallBack sending them the data.
Alternatively your contract could just have a method passing the ID of the client and getting the XML returned.

Here you can see a minimal implementation to get you started: [WCF named pipe minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353670/wcf-named-pipe-minimal-example)

Comment: but they need it as a console application

Comment: You can use whatever host you want, WinForms, Console Application, etc. Don't get confused by the name. A WCF service is not a Windows Service.

Comment: can you provide me with any tutorial to use it to understand it please ?

Comment: The tutorial should be the minimal implementation.