# c# opening 2 CMD windows

Tags: c#, cmd

I have been trying to open 2 CMD windows, but once I open the 2nd CMD window it just uses the 1st CMD window.

I tried duplicating the below code and using p2, and info2 so it would create a whole new cmd window, but it didn't help.

```
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
Console.Title = "PCRF";

Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;

p.StartInfo = info;
p.Start();

using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
{
    if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
    {
        sw.WriteLine("cd " + tbFilePath.Text + "\\SW\\bin\\Apps\\PCRFServer_new ");
        sw.WriteLine("runServer.bat " + ip_res  + userSelectedPcrfFilePath);       
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to see the p2 code so we can see if you've copied it completely.

Comment: Where's the code that tries to open two consoles?

Comment: Don't forget to dispose the process after you're done: `using (System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process())`

Comment: Possible Duplicate? [Open two console windows from C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379022/open-two-console-windows-from-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

You can run multiple instances of `cmd.exe` as detached processes with redirected input and/or output from within a c# program.  You cannot, however, create multiple *console windows* for them straightforwardly and still redirect the input or output back to yourself.

By default, whenever a windows process creates a child process, *it inherits the console window of the parent, if any*.  From [Process Creation Flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
>   0x00000010
>
> The new process has a new console, instead of inheriting its parent's console (the default). For more information, see [Creation of a Console](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682528%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

And from [Creation of a Console](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682528%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The system creates a new console when it starts a console process, a character-mode process whose entry point is the main function. For example, the system creates a new console when it starts the command processor. When the command processor starts a new console process, the user can specify whether the system creates a new console for the new process or whether it inherits the command processor's console.
>
> A process can create a console by using one of the following methods:
>
> - A GUI or console process can use the CreateProcess function with CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE to create a console process with a new console. (By default, a console process inherits its parent's console, and there is no guarantee that input is received by the process for which it was intended.)
> - A graphical user interface (GUI) or console process that is not currently attached to a console can use the [AllocConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944(v=vs.85).aspx) function to create a new console. (GUI processes are not attached to a console when they are created. Console processes are not attached to a console if they are created using CreateProcess with DETACHED_PROCESS.)

Unfortunately, the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class does not expose the `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` functionality, as can be seen from the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs.html#c50d8ac0eb7bc0d6).

I will note that your code does successfully create two `cmd.exe` processes that, while sharing the same console window, have different input streams and can both be used to execute batch files in parallel.  I tested this with the following code, and was able to see multiple instances of `cmd.exe` running in the Windows Task Manager, each doing its appointed task:

```
    private static void TestMultipleCmdLaunches()
    {
        TestCmdLaunch("cmd.exe", GetNextColorCommand(), "title PCRF", "echo window 1", "sleep 60");
        TestCmdLaunch("cmd.exe", GetNextColorCommand(), "title PCRF", "echo window 2", "sleep 60");
        TestCmdLaunch("cmd.exe", GetNextColorCommand(), "title PCRF", "yes 1");
        TestCmdLaunch("cmd.exe", GetNextColorCommand(), "title PCRF", "yes 2");
    }

    static string[] backgroundColors = 
        { "0F","1F","2F","3F","4F", "5F", "60", "70", "8F", "90", "A0", "B0", "C0", "D0", "E0"};
    static int lastBackgroundColor = 0;
    private static string GetNextColorCommand()
    {
        int nextColor = unchecked(Interlocked.Increment(ref lastBackgroundColor) % backgroundColors.Length);
        return "color " + backgroundColors[nextColor];
    }

    private static void TestCmdLaunch(string filename, params string [] commands)
    {
        using (Process p = new Process())
        {
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
            info.FileName = filename;
            info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            info.UseShellExecute = false;

            p.StartInfo = info;
            p.Start();

            using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
            {
                if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
                {
                    foreach (var cmd in commands)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(cmd);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The only problem is that the outputs appear intermingled in the console window.  Perhaps you want to redirect the output back to your own process anyway?