# Is there a way to open a new console window from a console application in c#

Tags: c#

We want to troll our teacher, we want to start a new console window when he inputs something (arbitrary value) invalid.

Is there a way that we could start a new console window from Main?

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

static void Main(string args)
{
    Process.Start();
}
```

Comment: It's duplicated. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379022/open-two-console-windows-from-c-sharp/27912557 or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697227/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-second-console-to-output-to-in-net-when-writing-a-co

Comment: [`Process.Start()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.8) with `cmd.exe`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp We tried running it and we get an error `"error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Process.Start()' [C:\Users\Julian\Desktop\Bellecour\c#\191205 - HW\191205 - HW.csproj]"`

Comment: @JaackoTorus Please [edit] and add your code.

Comment: @JaackoTorus You forgot the parameter: `Process.Start("cmd.exe");`

Answer (score 2):

Sure ;)

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe");
```

Comment: Thank you, we are beginners, and we couldn't decipher the other answers!

Comment: EDIT: NVM, I'm dumb, I figured it out ;) thanks for the help Hey sorry to bother you again, but we just tried this and it doesn't add a new console window, instead it prints `(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.` and then a new line